# Save XML DOM back to server file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a xml file on a server, which I retrieve like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onload = function() {

    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    //I modify the XML here!
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/car.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I now want to save the modifications back to the file on the server using Javascript. I tried `xmlhttp.open("POST"...` but it did not work. Any ideas would be a great help!

Edit:

So i'v given the PHP a go but cannot get it to work. Here is what i have:

```
$xmlFile = 'http://localhost:8888/car.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

$car = $_POST['car'];

echo $car;

$id = 0;

foreach($xml->data->car as $item)
{
    if($item['id'] > $id)
    {
        $id = $item['id'];
    }
}

$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<car></car>");
$newsXML->addAttribute('id', $id++);

$xml->appendChild(newsXML);

file_put_contents('http://localhost:8888/car.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Comment: Does your server actually have any business logic for handling changed data?

Comment: No it's just a local MAMP service. It's nothing commercial, just testing out for myself.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me when I used the term 'business logic', sorry! What I mean is, how are you handling the saving of the new data on the server?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm not handling it. Thats what I'm not sure how to do. I just want to replace the file currently there on the server with the new data modified from the javascript on the webpage. Hope I make sense.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language.

Comment: I would like to do it using Javascript.

Comment: With your Client's JavaScript only you won't be able to write the file. You can use JavaScript to transfer the data, with AJAX for example. But there need to be sth on the server side (PHP, Java etc.) which handles the data and writes the file.

Comment: @Safinn — Fine. Pick a way to run JavaScript on your server. Node.js and Classic ASP are probably the two most common ways.

Comment: Would classic ASP work on a MAMP server? not an asp server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to assume the P in MAMP is PHP, which I don't know very well, but you'd create a PHP file that gets the updated data from a $_POST (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) object, build up a DOM tree in PHP and save it to whereever you need it to be.

I think that perhaps a form node element might be what you need to to as a form element has an action attribute(http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_ACTION.html) which defines what page will recieve the POST data. This page would handle the writing of the file, not the javascript.

The basics are that you'll need two files one file to contain a form element.
form.php:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
</form>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '!';
?>
```

Something like this should show you the basics of how data is submitted on a website, or you could drop the MAMP stack and just use NodeJS as has been suggested by others.

Comment: I understand but I have never used PHP so not sure how I would go about doing it.

Comment: @Safinn Added some example code for your reference.

Comment: Just gave PHP a go and edited my OP. Finding trouble.

Comment: Do you understand you can't write to URLs? You need to write to the file in the context of your local file system, which on a Mac will be something like /home/user/Dev/projectName/meh.xml.

Comment: Changed the location to: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/car.xml.. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that folder? Use some error handlers to find out exactly what is going wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: I made the folder chmod 777 and check for errors and there are none. :(

Comment: The problem seems to be this line: $xml->appendChild($newXML);

Comment: I think its because this '$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);' is not a DOM element. I should use addChild() instead of append but then i get error saying the parent it not permanent.

Comment: What does echo $xml show? According to the API simplexml_load_file returns a SimpleXMLElement object or false. If the object is false then you can't add anything but if it's a valid object I'd like to see the actual full error, also can you please update your code to show this?

Comment: echo $xml shows nothing but echo $xml->asXML() displays all the XML.

Comment: So on the final line you can print out the value of the of the XML you wish to write, but the file isn't getting written, is that correct?

Comment: I cannot print the XML i wish to write because I cannot append 'newsXML' to the content.

Comment: As per the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) simplexml_load_file returns a SimpleXMLElement object or false. SimpleXMLElement doesn't have an 'appendChild' method, you'd have to use something like 'addChild' which returns a reference to the child node. You then manipulate that child node and save the xml that way, please see the example listed in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. One little thing, my foreach loop does return the correct result. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, can you please update your code or provide a link to a where I can look at it?